# Runtime Enhancement in OSGi environment using code

Tags: osgi, openjpa, osgi-bundle, persistence.xml, openjpa-maven-plugin

Problem  : 
1.  JPA Classes/entities are in  Bundle 1 and Bundle 2 using same persistence unit
2.  Bundle 3 is trying to access(wrapper APIs for DB API abstraction) the classes in Bundle 1 and Bundle 2.
3.  Runtime enhancement is not working.

So what I am planning to do is to enhance the JPA entities using Code, where in just before the bundle 3 comes up, these entities in  Bundle 1 could be enhanced.
I am planning doing this as the runtime enhancement does not complete and the bundle 3 comes up . This leads to DB APIs(Bundle 3 APIs) failure as tables are not created.

Comment: Why don't you use compile time enhancement? OpenJPA can do that for you. Runtime bytecode manipulation is a very evil thing in my opinion and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem in a former project with openjpa and OSGi. Luckily, OpenJPA supports compile time enhancement which could be done via the openjpa maven plugin as described here: http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-maven.html

And there is also an eclipse maven connector which supports runtime-enhancement inside the IDE, which is really comfortable if you want to use remote deployment. http://openjpa-maven-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/